# Android: checking a view's background

Tags: java, android, logic

I have 3 buttons, all of them have the same background drawable by default (`subject_button`)

**What I want to do:**

When I click one button his background changes ( to `clicked_subject`), all the others remain with the default background, if I click one button after clicking another, the button I just clicked changes his background while the previous one gets back to the initial background, allowing only one button to have the `clicked_subject` background, if the diffrent button gets clicked again his background goes back to the initial one, leting all the buttons with the initial background.

**The problem:**

If I click the diffrent button, his background remains the same instead of changing back to the initial one.

**My logic:**

```
theButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);
theButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
//same for other 2

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getBackground() == ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.subject_button)) {

        theButton1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);
        theButton2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);
        theButton3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.clicked_subject);

    } else {

        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.subject_button);
    }
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by instead of changing only the background color on clicking the button, I also change the textColor, then I can check the textColor with `if (((Button) v).getCurrentTextColor() == Color.WHITE)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
private final List<Button> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();

// somewhere in your code
mButtons.add(mButton1);
mButtons.add(mButton2);
mButtons.add(mButton3);
mButton1.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
mButton2.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
mButton3.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);

private final View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (Button button : mButtons) {
            if (button == v) {
                // set selected background
            } else {
                // set not selected backround
            }
        }
    }
};
```

If you define a stateful drawable for your buttons, then you can simply change the onclick to this:

```
private final View.OnClickListener mClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (Button button : mButtons) {
            button.setSelected(v == button);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: With that remains the same problem, which is after clicking the selected button, the background is supposed to go back to the initial drawable

Answer (score 0):

For changing background color/image based on the particular event(focus, press, normal), you need to define a button selector file and implement it as background for button. For example **button_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:state_pressed="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/your_image1" /> <!-- pressed -->
     <item android:state_focused="true"
           android:drawable="@drawable/your_image2" /> <!-- focused -->
    android:drawable="@drawable/your_image3" <!-- default -->
 </selector>
```

then just apply it as :

```
 <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawable="@drawable/button_selector.xml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

"Pressed", "selected", "disabled" and such are `View` states. As such they're supposed to be handled automatically by Android and not by your click listeners.

This is achieved using `SateList`s, which control the look your Views sould have depending on which state(s) they're in. So you can easily set `subject_button` as the unpressed state, `clicked_subject` as the pressed state, and let Android take care of actually switching between them.

Full explanation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: How can I change a background of an iamge when another image gets clicked using a `ListState`?

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't need to, because Android should take care of it (if you lift your finger from a View, its state changes automatically). If your Views' state is connected, consider using radio buttons: http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton.html